# How to create a vector map from SVGs in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, svg

Is it possible to use QGIS to import an SVG of boundaries and export it as polygons, such as each region created by the boundaries is an individual polygon that shares edges with its neighbours?

If so, is it possible to have each of those polygons automatically assigned an ID?

Answer (score 1):

SVG aren't really a recognized GIS format and [GDAL doesn't really support it](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/svg.html). I really doubt your SVGs will be readable so you won't have any georeferencing nor data fields.

My suggestion would be to use a CAD program that can import SVGs to then export it as DXF. [FreeCad](https://www.freecad.org/) can do this, I use it all the time. You'll still have to georeference it.

Comment: No plugin needed any more to georeference vector formats. In newer QGIS version, the built-in georeferences can also georeference vectors. It can now be found in the menu `Layer`.

Comment: Hey, that's true! I never had to use it so it lapsed out of my memory from the changelog reads.